# What could be causing my transmission to slip?

Tags: chevrolet, transmission, automatic-transmission, trailblazer, slipping

Three days ago when I was leaving the store, I started up 2006 Chevy Trailblazer Ls and it wouldn't reverse. I tried to move forward and that wouldn't work either. When I switched from drive or reverse back to park, there was a loud clicking noise that occurred each time for a few seconds. A guy at the store who stated that he was a mechanic said that it was an issue with the transmission and suggested adding a quart of fluid, but that didn't solve the problem. Next, he suggested unhooking the negative battery cable and hooked it back up and the truck was able to move. I took it straight home which is about 2 minutes away from where I was at, but I noticed a reduction in power and a bumping noise when I accelerated. After getting the fluid level full, I was able to drive around with no issues. Today when I started up my truck, it went into reverse while parked and it felt like it was slipping again as I drove it. Have any of you experienced these symptoms, if so, what was the cause of it?

Comment: Any OB2 trans codes in the ecm?

Comment: I checked, and there are no codes coming up.

Comment: Any spots on the driveway (transmission fluid)?

Comment: There aren't any spots and the fluid is still at the full line.

Comment: If the fluid is at the full line, why did you add more transmission fluid? The only way you'd need to add tranny fluid is if you lost tranny fluid somewhere.

Comment: It was a little over a quart low on the day that I first noticed the problem. That same day, I added a quart and the next day I added another half of quart and that got it to the full line. I drove it for a few days without any issues, but yesterday it started acting up. I checked the trans fluid levels and it is still full which I am assuming that it means there is no leak that is causing the issue.